# multiple conditions inside click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

With this code and chk1 and chk2 as 0, is impossible to me to guess what is wrong with this simple code function.

As i know, there are many js ways to use click, like ".click()", ".on('click')" or ".onClick" but none of them works at all. Take a look of this example:

```
            regbtn.click(function() {
                            if(chk1 == 0){
                                if(chk2 == 1){
                                    box2.reverse();
                                    chk2 = 0;
                                }
                                box1.restart();
                                chk1 = 1;
                                }
                            });

        logbtn.click(function() {
                            if(chk2 == 0){
                                if(chk1 == 1){
                                    box1.reverse();
                                    chk1 = 0;
                                }
                                box2.restart();
                                chk2 = 1;
                                }
                            });
```

Is there any reason why this doesnt work properly? and which way is the newest and best to use of this 3 ways of click js functions.

**EDIT**

regbtn and logbtn are 2 buttons that open 2 diferent boxes, box1 and box2 respectively, chk1 and chk2 is to check if the other box is open and reverse it first if so.

Alert doesnt work at all in any place.

This is the initial code variables to work with:

```
    var regbox = document.getElementById("regbox"),
        logbox = document.getElementById("logbox"),
        regbtn = document.getElementById("regbtn"),
        logbtn = document.getElementById("logbtn");
    var chk1 = 0,
        chk2 = 0;
```

Comment: well, what are `regbtn` and `logbtn` and `box1` and `box2`?

Comment: put an alert inside the click method and see if you are getting inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply JQuery methods to DOM elements.

Try using JQuery selectors instead:

```
   var regbox = $("#regbox"),
        logbox = $("#logbox"),
        regbtn = $("#regbtn"),
        logbtn = $("#logbtn");
```

These return JQuery objects connected to the relevant DOM elements. The extensive (cross-browser) methods on JQuery object are what make it so powerful. If you find yourself using DOM elements directly that is often a sign of something that is less portable.

Comment: Awesome, Javascript and Jquery is a big black endless hole of void for me. Thanks a lot